# Named Query with List of object as input using JPA named query

Tags: jpa

Getting below QueryExecutionRequestException when I try to excecute update Named query using JPA repository.

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [update com.company.farmer.entity.FarmProducts p set p.isDeleted=:isDeleted where p.productId IN (:productIdsList_0, :productIdsList_1)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [update com.company.farmer.entity.FarmProducts p set p.isDeleted=:isDeleted where p.productId IN (:productIdsList_0, :productIdsList_1)]
```

Code:

```
@Repository
public interface FarmProductRepository extends JpaRepository<FarmProducts, Long> {

void deleteProduct(@Param("isDeleted") String isDeleted, @Param("productIdsList") List<Long> productIdsList);

}

@Override
public String deleteProductAndCategory(long categoryId, FarmProductIdsDTO farmProductIds) {
    farmProductRepository.deleteProduct(FarmerProductCategoryConstants.DELETE_YES_FLAG, farmProductIds.getFarmProductIds());

    return FarmerProductCategoryConstants.SUCCESS;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="farm_products")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude= "productCategory")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="FarmProducts.deleteProduct", query="update FarmProducts p set p.isDeleted=:isDeleted where p.productId IN (:productIdsList)") })
public class FarmProducts extends BaseModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "FARM_PRODUCT_GENERATOR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "FARM_PRODUCT_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "FARM_PRODUCT_GENERATOR_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "farm_product_id")
    public Long productId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "farm_product_category_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("products")
    public ProductCategory productCategory;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    public String product;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted")
    public String isDeleted;

}
```

I am trying to pass a list of productId to make the isDeleted as "N". But update functionality fails because of the QueryExecutionRequestException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Spring Data treats all queries as SELECT statements. If you have an UPDATE (or DELETE) statement you have you have to apply de `@Modifying` annotation on the query.
See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries